# ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings'

Tags: python, django

I just started up with django, after creating the models. I created a project poll. for the database migration.

```
      python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

It throws error :-

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mysite.settings
```

Here is how manage.py looks :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Here is how the directory structure looks :-

```
  .
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- manage.py
|-- polls
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- migrations
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- tests.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
|-- settings.py
|-- settings.pyc
|-- urls.py
|-- urls.pyc
|-- wsgi.py
`-- wsgi.pyc
```

Comment: Can we see manage.py, the problem arises probably because you did not add your main app folder to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Also could be import error inside mysite/settings.py file if it imports some other modules. Other circular import errors and such in your codebase might also trigger this.

Comment: just added manage.py !

Comment: What does you working directory look like, and show us your settings.py file.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa No, I cant see any errors in settings.py file, I am using eclipse pydev plugin.

Comment: This is because Django has some magic and might mask the actual import error what is happening.

Comment: Also please format your question as it now has formatting errors making it difficult to read

Comment: @user2475624 Well the problem might be because you renamed the main app directory that houses `settings.py`.